# smoothing a curved glass to avoid a black rendering

Tags: transparency, glass

I'm getting a common black rendering for a curved window. Using a subsurf helps a lot to fix it but I'm loosing then the sharp edges on the periphery.
Any suggestion to smooth the glass with no distortion on the outer edges?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Add supporting loops near the edges of the glass? (when using a subsurf)

Comment: If I understood your question right, I also think a loopcut near the edges would help and work the best (crtl + r)

Comment: You're perfectly right, thanks. Adding edge loops near the outer edges solved this issue (even without the subsurf). I still wonder why.